# Авторизация без логина и пароля

Tags: авторизация, php

Есть страница(гейт), скажем: http://myurl.com/enter_point_x456fz0091wep77.php

- внешних ссылок на неё нет нигде
- директории файлов скрыты апачем
- в robots.txt, .htaccess нигде ничего не указано
- подобрать такое название сложно (отличное от /admin, /login, /signin и тд)
- юзер без логина и пароля авторизируется через неё определенным exe-приложением

Если не брать в расчет снифф http(s) траффика и хистори браузера (тк браузера не будет, а будет своё ехе)

Какова вероятность что она всётаки "заиндексируется гуглом" или будет доступна общественности? Понимаю что вопрос глуп, но всё же очень интересует такой  подход. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: чем exe помешает сниффу ?

Comment: Есть такая головоломка http://zestriddle.ovh.org/ не индексируется роботами ни в какую ))

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, ну вот, я залип...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все поисковые боты как правило представляются в userAgent, если видите бота, выдавайте ему 404, и еще как вариант, раз авторизация через приложение, отправляйте в качестве реферера какой либо параметр однозначно идентифицирующий Ваше приложение, если же реферера нет или он не совпадает с реферером приложения, выдавайте так же 404.